# Rabbitmq not using config file on mac

Tags: macos, rabbitmq, homebrew

I've installed rabbitmq on mac with brew.
`(brew install rabbitmq)`

Added to export path to my .bash_profile 
`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"`

Added a config file:
config file(s) : /usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config

`[{rabbit, [{tcp_listeners, [8080]}, {loopback_users, []}]}].`

When I startup rabbitmq-server I get a log here:
/usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log:

`started TCP Listener on 127.0.0.1:5672`

Also I can't connect from other clients to the server.

http://127.0.0.1:15672 does work locally but not from other clients. 
(401 Unauthorized)

/usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log:

`=WARNING REPORT==== 31-Mar-2016::09:02:13 ===
HTTP access denied: user 'guest' - User can only log in via localhost`

Comment: How did you start the server?

Comment: terminal: rabbitmq-server
  `RabbitMQ 3.5.6. Copyright (C) 2007-2015 Pivotal Software, Inc.
  ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ##  ##
  ##########  Logs: /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
  ######  ##        /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log
  ##########
              Starting broker... completed with 10 plugins.`

Comment: Can you double-check in the log file the path to the configuration file?

Comment: config file(s) : /usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/7pjX_sSM7g4